# Generate a UUID string with ARC enabled

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I need to generate a UUID string in some code with ARC enabled.

After doing some research, this is what I came up with:

```
CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
NSString *uuidStr = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
CFRelease(uuid);
```

Am I correctly using `__bridge_transfer` to avoid leaking any objects under ARC?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Looks fine to me. This is what I use (available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1501325))

```
- (NSString *)uuidString {
    // Returns a UUID

    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    NSString *uuidString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuid);
    CFRelease(uuid);

    return uuidString;
}
```

**Edited to add**

If you are on OS X 10.8 or iOS 6 you can use the new [NSUUID](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to generate a string UUID, without having to go to Core Foundation:

```
NSString *uuidString = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
// Generates: 7E60066C-C7F3-438A-95B1-DDE8634E1072
```

But mostly, if you just want to generate a unique string for a file or directory name then you can use `NSProcessInfo`'s `globallyUniqueString` method like:

```
NSString *uuidString = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
// generates 56341C6E-35A7-4C97-9C5E-7AC79673EAB2-539-000001F95B327819
```

It's not a formal UUID, but it is unique for your network and your process and is a good choice for a lot of cases.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your answer. But what is the main difference between IDs generated with `NSUUID` and `NSProcessInfo`?

Comment: @Artem NSProcessInfo returns a `String` not a `UUID`. Also, it is only guaranteed to be unique for the same process. Useful if you just need a unique string.

Answer (score 42):

That looks correct to me.

You have CFRelease'd `uuid`, which is your responsibility from the `CFUUIDCreate()`

And you've transferred ownership of the string to ARC, so the compiler knows to release `uuidStr` at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 7):

From [clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.casts):

> *`(__bridge_transfer T)`* op casts the operand, which must have non-retainable pointer type, to the destination type, which must be a retainable object pointer type. ARC will release the value at the end of the enclosing full-expression, subject to the usual optimizations on local values.

So you are doing it right.