# UUID v1 Objective-C implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uuid

I want to implement UUID v1 in my iOS App.
I know that it is composed of Mac Address and timestamp as described in
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_.28MAC_address.29

Is there any objective-c implementation for this V1, based on CFUUID functions ?

I already have the mac address and the timestamp.

The UUID v1 description at Wikipedia : "The original (version 1) generation scheme for UUIDs was **to concatenate the UUID version with the MAC address of the computer that is generating the UUID, and with the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since the adoption of the Gregorian calendar in the West**"

It is also specified at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt , but it seems that it will need time to implement it.

I have found this link : http://www.famkruithof.net/guid-uuid-timebased.html who have a simple explanation for the steps to create a v1 UUID. Is there any existing implementation, before I implement it by my self?

Comment: I'm wondering why `CFUUID` is not good enough.

Comment: check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684551/generate-a-uuid-string-with-arc-enabled

Comment: just edited the question. I am talking of version 1 of UUID, where we will need to concatenate Mac address and timestamp, but it is really not very clear which steps to do.

Comment: @H2CO3 V1 of UUID is oft used when you want something that is both unique and can be traced back to the user.  I.e. it quite specifically does not guarantee privacy which is exactly why it has largely been abandoned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks it is common behavior to use framework functions. And that is use CFUUID. For example:

```
+(NSString*)get {
    NSString *deviceID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DeviceID"];
    if (!deviceID) {
        CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
        CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
        CFRelease(theUUID);
        deviceID = (NSString*)string;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:deviceID forKey:@"DeviceID"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    return deviceID;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this response, but does it match with version 1 of UUID.
" the original (version 1) generation scheme for UUIDs was to concatenate the UUID version with the MAC address of the computer that is generating the UUID, and with the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since the adoption of the Gregorian calendar in the West"

Comment: From the CFUUID class ref: "UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers), also known as GUIDs (Globally Unique Identifiers) or IIDs (Interface Identifiers), are 128-bit values guaranteed to be unique. A UUID is made unique over both space and time by combining a value unique to the computer on which it was generated—usually the Ethernet hardware address—and a value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since October 15, 1582 at 00:00:00." So I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one. It may be helpful to you

```
 +(NSString*) Create_UDID
 {
      CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
      CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
      CFRelease(theUUID);

      NSString* strString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string];
      NSString *strValue = [strString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-"withString:@""];

    if (strValue == nil) {
         strValue = @"";
     }

      return strValue;
 }
```