# Observing user interactions

Tags: ios

I wish to track a set of data my educational app generates based on user challenges. Every nth challenge I want the app to send these metrics to my server so I can observe various things about the app.

Further, and most important, **I need to uniquely identify each instance of my app so that I can watch the trends of a single user.** I wish to persist this number through the life of the user's interaction with my program in an anonymous kind of way, and persist over multiple removal / installations on the same device.

Bonus points for what your opinion of the standard method of reporting these metrics to a web server are. XML? JSON? Simple NSURL's?

Bonus points for links to relevant Apple Documentation.

DISCLAIMER: (due to past experiences...)
I am relatively new to stack overflow. If this post doesn't conform to the standards of this site, please explain why before voting me off of the island.

Comment: You are asking for opinions, stackoverflow should be more about specific programming questions

Comment: Hey antonio, thanks for your input. I am asking a specific question regarding what code/methods to use here, in order to say "I am an app, This is my number" and recognize that. I could try and guess but that would just be wasteful. FWIG, and also according to Abizem, in his post below, this is a thorny topic.

Comment: It's not thorny - it's quite clear. You can't tie an app to a device in any permanent manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't tie a device to a user unless you set up a username password combination.  Nothing else will work if you expect to handle app removal, installation, or device upgrades.

As for preferred data-type. My preference is JSON. But that's just a preference and you'll get lots of other differing replies. Hence it's a sort of pointless question.

Comment: Where can I see that in the Apple Docs? Thanks for your help.

Comment: -- hard to even envision what section this would be under....

Comment: Where can you see what in the Apple Docs? The only way to get a permanent device identifier used to be the UDID method, which is now deprecated. Other messages are not permanent identifiers, they are not guaranteed to be the same after you remove and reinstall an app. And what do you plan on doing when a user buys a new phone or iPad? How do you intend to reconcile his app usage then?

Comment: Oh ok, so what you are saying, is, there *used* to be a method that allowed this and now they don't. No documentation required because it does not exist - anymore. My app is so simple I really don't care if the tracking persists over multiple installations.

Comment: Since you don't have a method of getting a permanent identifier, that would be the answer. It's actually a sensible measure if you think about it. Devices move around, get updated, sold, stolen, etc.

Comment: If you don't care then just use identifierForVendor. But if you don't need to keep track, why even bother to use an identifier.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. For a fallback position - Is there an apple-approved method of creating an unique ID for my app - which I can use to track the app's user data? in example:

 - someNSmethod to get a unique number - store that in my app's user.plist

Comment: Here are a couple of ways http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684551/generate-a-uuid-string-with-arc-enabled/10469233#10469233

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16680879/1671729)  It explains what identifiers are constant when and in what situations they are not.  He talks about the identifierforvendor and advertisingidentifier that are now the only supported unique identifiers you can access.  They took away the UUID tracking as well as the MAC address method.  You can still get the device serial number, but that method uses code that will get your app rejected by apple's app store review process.